# VBA- Copy and paste error 1004

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I was doing a code for vba and wondering why I received a runtime error 1004 when attempting to paste in sheets "Datasheet". It tells me the information cannot be pasted as the copy area and paste area are not the same size and shape.

Is there anyway to work around this?

```
If (Not (rowmatched) And k = referencesheetcols) Then
    range2.Copy
    Sheets(referencesheetname).Range("a1:a6000").Cells(p, 1).Offset(2, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    p = p + 1
    Sheets("Datasheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 1).Offset(2, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    q = q + 1
End If

Next
End If
Next
```

Comment: You've only pasted part of your code... It's impossible to konw what else is going on. Or did you not mean to paste the last `next`, `end if` and `next`... What is the initial value of `p` and `q` - and what *is* `p` and `q` (give them real names). Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/936740/edit) and make it clear, or else it will probably be closed...

Comment: Also., what is the value of `range2`? What is `k` (use real words)?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer: Resolved using resize for the target cells.